# Not able to add pardot campaign tracking code in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, html, pardot

I am creating website using Lightning web component (LWC) on communities that has a number of pages.
I want to track the activities on each page using pardot tracking code. But seems like it is not possible add it directy as it contains script tags which is not allowed in LWC.
Below is the code of one of the pages:

```
<template>
 <div class="evencorner-bg">
 <h1 class="eventcorner_h1_c-suite">Inside Leadership</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
<template for:each={leaderShipArray} for:item='item'>
 <div key={item.Id} data-id={item.Id}>
 <div class="column xscol_global">
        <img src={item.Event_Banner__c} class="largeimgcss" />
        <div class="margintopdivlarge">
        <br/> <p class="trendingvidtext">inside leadership</p>
        <br/> <p class="largeimgtextsubp1">{item.Name}</p>
        <br/> <div class="largeimgtextsubp2">{item.Short_Event_Description__c} </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="row insideleadRow">
          <div class="column insideleadCol1">
          <img src={calendarIcon} class="Icon_img" /> 
          <lightning-formatted-date-time
          value={item.Event_Start_Date__c}
          time-zone="UTC">
        </lightning-formatted-date-time>
        <span style="margin-left: 5px;">•  <lightning-formatted-date-time 
          value={item.Event_Start_Time__c} 
          hour="2-digit" 
          minute="2-digit"
          time-zone="UTC" 
          ></lightning-formatted-date-time></span>
          </div>
          <div class="column insideleadCol2">
          <a class="insideleadregbtn" href={item.DetailURL__c}>Register Now</a>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
 </div>
 </template>
 </div>
</template>
```

When i add my pardot campaign tracking code right before the  at the end, i get the following errors

```
LWC1051: Forbidden tag found in template: '<script>' tag is not allowed.

Invalid expression { function async_load(){ var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://pi' : 'http://cdn') + '.pardot.com/pd.js'; var c = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; c.parentNode.insertBefore(s, c); } - LWC1060: Template expression doesn't allow FunctionExpression
```

Please help me how can add my tracking code here.
It would be great help.
​​​​​​​Thanks​​​​​​​

Comment: You should probably add your tracking code directly to the community using the settings in community builder. You'll be able to edit Head markup.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for the response and yes it worked pretty well. Just a quick query. I want to integrate a form handler on the registration page of my community website. is possible to be done?